# Logout so the back button doesn't return to profile

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

The code I have below is an `OnClick` logout method from an app. All it does at present is return the user to the login page, however if the user presses the back button on the Android phone, it brings them back to the page they've just logged out from, which I don't want it to. How can I change my code so that it doesn't let the back button take the user back to their profile without logging in again?

```
public void OpenMain(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
}
```

The php code for logging in is below:

```
<?php
    require "conn.php";

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $mysql_qry = "select * from users where username like '$username' and password like '$password';";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo "Successful login";
    }
    else{
        echo "Login not successful";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Check if the user is logged in before it loads the profile page. If they're not, redirect them back to the login page.

Comment: As you tagged `php` logout means you end his session in your server side , and tell the client to remove whatever session cookies he is sending

Comment: @DiddleDot how do i do this?

Comment: @Accountantم how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add flags that specify that the new activity will replace the old one:

```
public void openMain(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: So if I add this code what should happen when I click the 'back' button?

Comment: I added the code but an error appears saying 'cannot reslove symbol 'intent'', know why this is?

Comment: Okay thank you I fixed that error and the code works now. I'll accept your answer as being correct